# how to set Environment variable in Json file. ( Clients Secrets, Client Id etc)?

Tags: python, json, environment-variables, credentials, production-environment

my client-secret.json contains something like..

```
        {
          "web": {
            "client_id": "asdfjasdljfasdkjf",
            "client_secret": "1912308409123890",
            "redirect_uris": ["https://www.example.com/oauth2callback"],
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
          }
        }
```

and this will be use in following python script method.

```
service = create_service('path_to_directory/client-secret.json', 'gmail')
```

Its working fine. there is no issue with that .but now i want to take my application in production but i dont know how to handle these secrets in production. can i use Environment variable in Json file or any other good way to handle this.

Comment: you just have to make sure that the json file that contains secret can not be accessed by anyone who does not have such right (e.g.: do not put the json file in public_html directory)

Answer (score -1):

A smart way of handling the environment variables in Python is to use `try/except` and a `.ini` config file! Like so.

```
import os
from configparser import RawConfigParser

try:
    config = RawConfigParser()
    config.read("/path/to/your_file.ini")
except:
    pass

try:
    DATABASE_USER = config.get("database", "DATABASE_USER")
except:
    DATABASE_USER = os.environ["DATABASE_USER"]
```

Where the `.ini` file appears like this:

```
[database]
DATABASE_USER: root
```

So, basically, if your .ini file doesn't exist, Python will automatically retrieve the environment variabile (that can eventually come from a docker-compose or a Dockerfile). You can use any sort of file, even your Json example with `json.dumps()`!

Comment: so you are saying that i have to handle this with docker-compose file?

Comment: in general, you can set up those environment variables however you want.. simply, docker is one of the most smart, safe, versatile and agile ways to put a product in production. you can even put your environment variables in your dockerfile with the EXPORT without needing a whole docker-compose.. you can even make a script that exports environment variables based on input and later avoiding to save the command in history.. but generally, the best way on backend-side is to retrieve environment variables